# Adding records (Row/ Column) to DataGridView; Collection already belongs to a DataGridView control VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, syntax-error, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewrow

I'm looking for some help with an issue I am having.
I have multiple text files, in a folder. The folder can have an "unlimited" amount of text files in it, although typically 2-150 files 
http://gyazo.com/5f314d1ca374abf9f813914609dd931d (images for this + below, can't embed due to lack of reputation)

Each file then contains an "unlimited" (although typically 0-20 lines) amount of data inside it. Line 1 being the "test number" and line 2 being the "test result" - as seen in the image above

My Data Grid View has 3 columns in it (Username, test number, test result) - as seen in the image above

When running my code below; first record being added to the Data Grid View works perfectly, but the second (or any record after the first) the error occurs:
http://gyazo.com/0d492b97d918853e62c55ee314f3f181 (image) or error message:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Collection already belongs to a
>   DataGridView control. This operation is no longer valid.  at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection.Add(DataGridViewCelldataGridViewCell)
>   at SpellingBee.TeacherMultiResults.TeacherMultiResults_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)"

This error occurs on the `DGVRow.Cells.Add(DGVCell) 'add cell to row`

One thing I don't want to do is change any of my text file/ folder structures, even though I'm aware that it is currently inefficient storage.

How can I fix this error? I'm using VB.net (Visual Studios 2013)

If you need any more information, please just ask

Many thanks.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO

Public Class TeacherMultiResults

    Dim AmountOfFiles
    Dim LineCount As Integer = 0
    Dim FileName As IO.FileInfo
    Dim DGVRow As New DataGridViewRow
    Dim DGVCell As DataGridViewCell
    Dim Username As String = ""
    Dim TestNumber As Integer = 0
    Dim TestResult As Integer = 0

    Private Sub TeacherMultiResults_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(LoadForm.CurrentDirectory & "\UserResults\") 'selects directory
        Dim FileNames As IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles()
        Dim Files As IO.FileInfo

        For Each Files In FileNames 'list the names of all files in the specified directory
            Username = Files.ToString
            Username = (Username.Substring(0, Username.Length - 4)) 'removes the .txt from the name

            Try
                LineCount = File.ReadAllLines(LoadForm.CurrentDirectory & "\UserResults\" & Username & ".txt").Length 'amount of lines in file
                If LineCount > 1 Then
                    Dim Information As New System.IO.StreamReader(LoadForm.CurrentDirectory & "\UserResults\" & Username & ".txt") 'opens file
                    LineCount = LineCount / 2 'halfs line count
                    For i = 0 To LineCount - 1
                        TestNumber = Information.ReadLine() 'reads line to variable
                        TestResult = Information.ReadLine() 'reads line to variable
                        i = i + 1 'adds one to i

                        DGVCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell 'create a new DGV text box cell
                        DGVCell.Value = Username 'add value to DGV text box cell
                        DGVRow.Cells.Add(DGVCell) 'add cell to row

                        DGVCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell 'create a new DGV text box cell
                        DGVCell.Value = TestNumber 'add value to DGV text box cell
                        DGVRow.Cells.Add(DGVCell) 'add cell to row

                        DGVCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell 'create a new DGV text box cell
                        DGVCell.Value = TestResult 'add value to DGV text box cell
                        DGVRow.Cells.Add(DGVCell) 'add cell to row

                        DGV_MultiResults.Rows.Add(DGVRow) 'add row to DGV

                    Next
                    Information.Close() 'Close read
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception 'if file won't read
                MsgBox(ex.ToString) 'show error
                Exit Try
            End Try 'end of try

        Next 'end of files

    End Sub
```

I hope that somebody can help me with this issue, I understand it's fairly simple to fix most probably although I can't seem to find a solution to the error!

Many thanks, Toby.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a DataGridView, it is generally easier to just build an object list and then bind it to the DGV using the built-in data binding features.

For your example, it would look like this:

```
' Read the files, build objects as you go and add them to a list
Dim lst = New List(Of TeacherMultiResults)

' Replace this part with your file reading code...
Dim t1 = New TeacherMultiResults With {.Username = "Bob", .TestNumber = 1, .TestResult = 75}
lst.Add(t1)
Dim t2 = New TeacherMultiResults With {.Username = "Rick", .TestNumber = 1, .TestResult = 85}
lst.Add(t2)
Dim t3 = New TeacherMultiResults With {.Username = "Zoe", .TestNumber = 1, .TestResult = 95}
lst.Add(t3)

' Bind the list to the DataGridView
Dim bindList = New BindingList(Of TeacherMultiResults)(lst)
Dim bindSrc = New BindingSource

bindSrc.DataSource = bindList
grid.DataSource = bindSrc
```

Your grid should display each item of your list.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Imports System.ComponentModel was required to get the BindingList to work.

Comment: although this method doesn't seem to work. I've made a new question as this one has been answered, although not correctly. Please see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894821/adding-records-row-column-to-data-grid-view-no-text-adding-runtime-error-wit)